# Why does this throw a Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, web, typeerror

Why does this throw a "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"?

```
function Game () {
    this.reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame;

    this.gameLoop = function () {
        this.reqAnimFrame(this.gameLoop); // It's thrown on this line
    };
}

var game = new Game();
game.gameLoop();
```

Comment: It is a method so you need `()` after this.gameLoop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `this.reqAnimFrame`, the context for `window.requestAnimationFrame` is no longer `window`, but becomes whatever `this` is (in this case, an instance of `Game`). Most built-in functions don't work unless you call them with the correct contexts. (For example, something like

`var func = console.log;
func("blah");`

doesn't work as well, for the same reason).

To fix this, you should either just use the original form: `window.requestAnimationFrame`, or you can bind it to the correct context when you store it:

`this.reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window);`

Comment: I want it to run in the function not in window, that's why i made it, but thanks I can call `this.reqAnimFrame(this.gameLoop.apply(this));` then.

Comment: @Hendry I think you mean `this.reqAnimFrame(this.gameLoop.bind(this))`?

Comment: yes! thanks! that works much better than what i had!